# How can I update values in MySQL database table to conform to a different pattern?

Tags: mysql, function, relational-database

I intend to clean some data in a MySQL database table for some data that was not properly captured. The table in question contains numerous columns but the column of interest is named **id_number**. Sample data in the column is captured as follows: **BUT3345622019**, **PAC1034412016**, etc. in that format. However, my requirement is to re-write each value in the column replacing it with values like **BUT-3-3456-2/2019**, **PAC-1-0344-1/2016**, etc. I have been thinking about the perfect SQL script (in MySQL) to solve the problem but so far I have not been successful. The table name is **users**. I am requesting for some help on this particular problem.

Comment: Use the next functions: [SUBSTRING()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring), [CONCAT()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat). The query itself is absolutely trivial: `UPDATE table SET column = {converting expression} [WHERE column REGEXP {format checking pattern}]`.

Comment: *I am requesting for some help on this particular problem.* Show your attempts. Nobody will write this query instead of you.